# 802.11 Wi-Fi Module that allows direct access to PHY layer

Tags: rf, wifi, 802.11

I am looking for a Wi-Fi RF chip that allows me to bypass the MAC layer. I want to simply select a modulation, frequency and tx power, then add a simple payload and transmit (I am aware there more configurations but that is the idea). I want also to be able to build my own MAC layer on top it. I have been looking everywhere on Digikey, RF Components, Mouser etc. but I do not see any chip that has a clear indication in its datasheet that it allows raw tx/rx. Any idea of any chip that does that?

EDIT: to clarify, this is a common feature in IoT chips like AT86RF215. There are 31 different 802.15.4 modulations including OFDM. There is a similiar set of modulations for 802.11 standard with bitrates from 1 Mbps up to 9.6 Gbps. But I do not see a chip that shows explicitly in datasheet how a specific modulation is selected like the IoT AT86RF215 chip. I know this can be done with SDR in a USRP. But I am looking for an existing off-the-shelve module. Or is there a technical reason why there is no solution for that?

Comment: You could do this with the old CC1000, but that was 802.15.  ChipCon also got purchased by TI, so not sure what it's called now.

Comment: This smells like a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641431/atmega32-networking

Comment: @brhans the question  you referred points to a low rate sub-GHz solution for 802.15.4 PHYs. I am looking for a module for high through 802.11 PHYs.

Comment: Wifi operates on the application layer, phy's operate on the link layer. You can't have a Wifi phy. How will it know where to send the packet? What you are looking for is an ESP8266, but you will need to program it.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thank you so much! this is exctly right! I do not want the MAC layer, I want to program my own MAC on top of the PHY so I want a chip that I can program myself as you said. I have suspected the ESP8266 and ATWILC1000 but I failed to see any programming guide at that level for it. If you happen to know where that guide could be, I would be extremely grateful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for a Wi-Fi RF chip that allows me to bypass the MAC layer.

But: modern Wi-Fi chips almost universally already don't do MAC at all. It's your operating system's infrastructure that's in charge of that.

> I want to simply select a modulation, frequency and tx power, then add a simple payload and transmit (I am aware there more configurations but that is the idea).

That's not "bypassing the MAC and using the PHY", that's "replacing the PHY with something else".

That's basically an SDR. A Wi-Fi RF chip will not let you do arbitrary things – it's technically designed to produce an OFDM waveform of one of a very limited set of subcarriers. The synthesizers will also only allow you a finite set of frequencies, and power will also be constrained by Wi-Fi applications.

Comment: Thank you. I believe we have different notions of what is a PHY and a MAC. MAC for me is CSMA/CA but OFDM is PHY. Even in this case, I want to simply choose the MCS and then send a raw packet  The closest solution I saw was sending 802.11 specific packets using injection (aircrack or scapy). But I failed to select the specific MCS/rate I for the transmission. If I put it differently, I want to get down to the SPI instruction that configures the chip with an MCS and the SPI instruction that loads the frame or gets packet from the receive buffer.

Comment: ah. So, yeah, that's definitely what you would read from a programming manual, or from the driver source code. But *all* wifi chipsets would do that: tell them the bits they need to transmit, and the MCS to use, and they'll do that.

Comment: Muller,  do you actually know of even one chip that does that where you actually have the manual for it? I mean I appreciate your comment but I don't find it helpful to indicate that _all_ chips support it without showing me even one example. Thank you .

Comment: Every single device supported by the [`mac80211` framework](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/mac80211) is a *softmac* device, where the MAC functionality is handled by host software, and not by the device itself. So, for example, the Atheros AR9271 which I'm using *right now* to talk to you is such a chip! It's *really* the standard way to implement a wifi device these days.

Comment: Documentation: Well, go ahead and read the Linux kernel source! That's what counts as documentation-as-it-will get for many players in the Wifi field, unless you buy > 10 Million chips and sign an NDA (leaked confidential documentation aside). You'll learn a lot on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yyFiLFx4Mg

Comment: If you want something where you can have a perfect look inside, and a wonderful community and developers that help you, take a look at the [Openwifi](https://github.com/open-sdr/openwifi) solution.

Comment: Generally, https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation is a good place to start

Comment: Sorry wrong youtube link above, was meant to send https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOcYTqoSQ68